# link dependent android ndk cmake project to main android ndk library project

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, cmake-modules

I have 2 modules in this project: `app` and `libdatacpp`
`libdatacpp` is mainly a C++ project but uses some java code
`app` is mainly a java project, but uses some c++ code

[image: Structure of the project]

When building the project, I get c++ linker errors for undefined functions from `libdatacpp`, because the `app` project doesn't link `libDataCpp.o`

In my cmake for `app`, I am linking against `libDataCpp` like this:

```
target_link_libraries(
        native-lib
        DataCpp)
```

I also link against the other project in the `app` module's `build.gradle` like this:

```
dependencies {
    api project(':libdatacpp')
```

How can I get the `app` module to automatically link against my `libdatacpp` module?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to provide `libdatacpp` native library for other AndroidStudio projects through .aar, then you need to use [prefab](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/native-dependencies?buildsystem=cmake&agpversion=4.1) feature.

But if these native library is part of your own project, then I don't see the need to put it in the .aar, just put its stuff (sources and CMakeLists.txt) in a subfolder and add it to build by using `add_subdirectory (datacpp)` in your main CMake.

Comment: Both native libraries are my own projects, so I want to build the other projects as dependencies when mine is built. The `add_subdirectory` method seems to work when I have one dependent library, but how would this work if my library is dependent on another library project? When I put `add_subdirectory` in the main app's cmake file, I get an error building the dependent library (cannot find `libDataCpp`)

The dependencies of my project are: `app` depends on `async-cpp` which depends on `data-cpp`

Comment: You need other main cmake file (not via app's cmake) where you will add to build your libraries via add_subdirectory command: ```add_subdirectory(data-cpp) add_subdirectory(async-cpp) add_subdirectory(app)```

Comment: How should the root cmakelists be structured? I'm using the app's cmakelists and doing add_subdirectory for data-cpp and async-cpp, and it is still giving me `cannot find -lDataCpp`

Comment: Onсe again, you need another up level root cmake not app's cmake where you add via  ```add_subdirectory``` all subdirectories.

Comment: Do you have an example of what that root cmake should look like? I just don't know how it needs to be structured basically

Comment: I can't make it something linkable without creating a library, so I don't really know what needs to go there

Comment: Here the example of project with root cmake https://github.com/nkh-lab/ndk-capi-hello-world, and do not forget to switch to it in your app/build.gradle like this: https://github.com/nkh-lab/ndk-capi-hello-world/blob/master/capi-hello-world/app/build.gradle#L31

Comment: I added a root CmakeLists that adds all the modules with add_subdirectory, and I still get the same error. Gradle is pointing to the main CmakeLists.

Comment: Look at this: https://github.com/lufinkey/async-cpp/pull/1